# Linq to Entities: multiple criteria query for one table

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, criteria

```
            using (WinFileContextContainer c = new WinFileContextContainer())
            {
            IQueryable<File> dbfiles = (from f in c.File
                                         where //(f.Category.Any((category => category.name == categoryname)) &&  
                                               f.alive //&&
                                               //f.description == "" &&
                                               //f.Category.Count == 1)
                                         select f);
             // the rest....
             }
```

The query works only as it is now - I left just one criteria (the rest is in comment sections). But I want the other criteria to be taken into account too. I tried with multiple "where"s :D or all the criteria in brackets with one "where", but still no success. I'm kinda new to LINQ so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work:

```
                IQueryable<File> dbfiles =
            c.File.Where(f => f.Category.Any(cat => cat.name == categoryname) &&
                                               f.alive &&
                                               f.description == null &&
                                               f.Category.Count == 1);
```